# Why do my matplotlib 2nd axis labels not line up

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm plotting some data in a grid, with labels for both a sample ID and, on separate axes generated with `twinx`and `twiny`, the key parameters of those samples.  Labels and their associated ticks should be centred on the grid cells they apply to.  The X axes are fine, but the second (right) Y axis is misaligned with the first.  Quite possibly related, the Y range is truncated from both ends - the first and last cells are about 2/3 the height of the other 3.

I've explicitly set `ylim` the same for both sets of axes, but it feels like `ax.set_ylim([4.5,-0.5])` is being ignored - commenting it out doesn't change anything.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#labels
rowlabels=['A','B','C','D','E']
columnlabels=['1','2','3','4','5','6']
rowparameters=['700','320','280','240','200']
columnparameters=['28','34','40','44','50','60']

#fake data
inputarray=np.random.randint(0,10,(5,6))

#plot the data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(inputarray, cmap='inferno')

# draw gridlines between cells instead of at ticks
for xpos in np.arange(-0.5,6.5,1):
    plt.axvline(xpos,color='white')
    plt.axvline(xpos,color="black", linestyle=":")
for ypos in np.arange(-0.5,5.5,1):
    plt.axhline(ypos,color='white')
    plt.axhline(ypos,color="black", linestyle=":")  

#ID labels  
ax.set_xlim([-0.5,5.5])
ax.set_ylim([4.5,-0.5])
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,6,1),columnlabels)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,5,1),rowlabels)

#parameter labels
axy2=ax.twinx()
axy2.set_ylim([4.5,-0.5])
axy2.set_yticks(np.arange(0,5,1),rowparameters)
axx2=axy2.twiny()
axx2.set_xlim([-0.5,5.5])
axx2.set_xticks(np.arange(0,6,1),columnparameters)
    
plt.show()
```

Adding a `colorbar` makes it look worse, but is informative:

[image]

```
fig.colorbar(data,ax=ax, location='right', pad=0.15, label="Signal intensity / counts")
```

The primary (left) Y axis labels are correctly positioned with respect to the cells, but he axis bounds aren't respected.  The secondary Y labels don't line up with the cells, neither are they evenly distributed over the axis (though their separation is equal).  The axis labels that I also added before this test make not difference

Eventually each cell might have to be subdivided, so I'm looking to keep the general approach.  But the number of cells (6×5) is fixed.  They should be drawn square.

Comment: The source for matplotlib.axes._base.py contains the note *"To ensure that the tick marks of both y-axes align, see   `~matplotlib.ticker.LinearLocator`."*.  But, at least using the approach in  [this answer to *How to create equal number of primary and secondary y-axes ticks with matplotlib?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28575366/2583476) doesn't make any difference (whether or not I subsequently overwrite the tick locations).   It does seem heavily dependent on the  secondary y axis (I may add more on that when I've pinned it down)